# Intuition for degree of maps ($S^n \rightarrow S^n$)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I understand the definition and some properties, but i was just wondering, is there some intuition behind the degree of a map $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$?

The identity has degree $1$, the antipodal map has degree $-1$. What are maps with degree $0$? Are they constant?

Comment: I guess you could say it's the amount of times the domain $S^n$ wraps around the target $S^n$ (but with an added sign).

Comment: "What are maps with degree 0? Are they constant?" Up to a deformation yes.

Comment: Also, note that the antipodal map has degree $-1$ when $n$ is even, but has degree $1$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: The idea of "measuring how many times the domain wraps around the target" can be made precise in some ways, too. E.g. if you know the homology definition, you can represent a generator of $H_n(S^n)$ by a triangulation and the degree is the multiple of itself to which this generators gets pushed forward by $f$. If $f$ is smooth, this can also be observed by counting the (oriented) number of preimages of a generic point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to use the case $n = 1$ as a motivating example. The map $S^1 \to S^1$ in which the domain gets wrapped around the target $k$ times has degree $\pm k$, where the sign depends on whether or not you throw in a reflection. The same idea is more or less true for higher-dimensional spheres, though it gets slightly harder to visualise.

And yes, the special case of degree $0$ is the case in which you wrap around the target $0$ times. Up to a continuous deformation that's the same as a constant map.